# Disable AWS IoT * Wildcard Usage

Tags: mqtt, amazon-iam, iot, aws-iot

Been working with AWS IoT for a few weeks now and it's pretty sick! It's very easy to connect and subscribe to MQTT topics with a single `iot:ClientId`. I like the fact that you can connect with a `iot:ClientId` and create IAM policies to stop users from subscribing to topics that don't include the `iot:ClientId` they used to connect.
I have security concerns with a single feature of IoT...... The use of the `*` wildcard. Hackers could easily connect to the IoT core cloud with `*` as their `iot:ClientId`. This would then allow them to subscribe to any topic regardless of `iot:ClientId`. I am wondering if there are IAM policies I could create to stop developers from using the `*` wildcard in place of their `iot:ClientId`. I am looking for a solution that doesn't include defining static `iot:ClientId` in my IAM policy. I'm not sure why I can't find any actual examples of a solution for this problem as I'm sure there are a lot of people that hate the IoT wildcard system. Anyway, hoping for a solution that contains a zip tight IAM policy JSON example for `iot:Connect`. This is what I have so far:

```
...
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "iot:Connect"
                Resource: 
                  - !Sub arn:aws:iot:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:client/${!iot:ClientId}
...
```

Comment: The hacker also needs a valid certificate to connect - doesn't that address most of the issues you raise?

Comment: I am worried that if there is a user using my app, they might try to look at the topics of other users.

Comment: You need to design your topic hierarchy to prevent this and use appropriate IoT policies. e.g. restrict a client to topics using the `iot:Receive`/`iot:Subcribe` policies. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-policy-actions.html and some explicit examples in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/pub-sub-policy.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use an IAM variable in the policy. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/basic-policy-variables.html